# How to make a graphic where one image points to two other images with arrows in latex?

Tags: latex, tikz

I want to create a graphic like the one in the attached image in latex, where each box represents an image (a graphic I want to insert). I also want to be able to write a word over the arrows that point from one image to another. [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,node distance=2em]
 \node(a){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};
 \node[right=of a](b){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}};
 \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Two graphics.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,node distance=2em]
 \node(a){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
 \matrix[right=of a,row sep=2em] {
 \node(b){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}};\\
 \node(c){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};\\
 };
 \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
 \draw[->] (a) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Three graphics.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

visit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527216/diagrams-arrows